# Properties inheritance problems in Python

Tags: python

Some time ago I was developing a python application and I used a lot of properties in my classes but I get into troubles when I tried to override the behavior of the accessors of a base class in a derived one. This is a sketch of my problem:

```
class Person(object):

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value


class Mr(Person):    

    @name.setter
    def name(self,value):
        self._name = "Mr. "+value



p = Person()
p.name = "John"

print p.name

m = Mr()
m.name = "John"

print m.name
```

When you run it you get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/bad.py", line 20, in <module>
    class Mr(Person):    
  File "/home/user/Desktop/bad.py", line 22, in Mr
    @name.setter
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

When I faced this problem I didn't had time to find an answer, I just used a plain getters and setters or rethink my logic so I did not need to override accessors, but now I'm trying to answer my question and study in some books, so far I had only found this approach:

```
class Person(object):

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = self._fix_name(value)

    def _fix_name(self,value):
        return value


class Mr(Person):    

    def _fix_name(self,value):
        return "Mr. "+value



p = Person()
p.name = "John"

print p.name

m = Mr()
m.name = "John"

print m.name
```

When I run this I get:

```
John
Mr. John
```

Which is what I want, but the problem is that `_fix_name` is accessible outside the class, besides it is an extra method I need to add for every property accessor I want to override, etc.

So the question is:
Is there some "good" way of doing this? Or, Is there any PEP that address this issue?
I think some kind of `@overrides` decorator could solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Mr(Person):

    @Person.name.setter
    def name(self,value):
        self._name = "Mr. "+value
```

Comment: Oh, A really easy solution, I don't know why when I tried exactly the same didn't work for me in the past! But its right! Thanks